# symfony2 doctrine.dbal.connection_factory with ssl?

Tags: database, symfony, ssl

I connect to a remote database from within my symfony2 app with this code

```
    $connectionFactory = $this->container->get('doctrine.dbal.connection_factory');
    $conn = $connectionFactory->createConnection(array(
        'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
        'user' => 'mattias',
        'password' => 'fdfsdf',
        'host' => 'fs1.rrtgy.se',
        'dbname' => 'csmedia',
    ));
    return $conn;
```

Is there a parameter I can set to do it using SSL?

The equivalent of something like this:

```
$link = mysql_connect("192.112.7.18","test","testpass",false,MYSQL_CLIENT_SSL)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try add to createConnection array 'driverOptions'

```
$conn = $connectionFactory->createConnection(array(
        'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
        'user' => 'mattias',
        'password' => 'fdfsdf',
        'host' => 'fs1.rrtgy.se',
        'dbname' => 'csmedia',
        'driverOptions' => array(
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA   =>'/path/to/ssl-ca.pem'
        ),
    ));
```

More info about [MYSQL SSL constants](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php#pdo.constants.mysql-attr-ssl-ca).

Notice, that some constants were added at php 5.3.7

However, SSL options are silently ignored in (at least) version 5.3.8: see the [bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=55870).